# Need to manually refresh the page to update it

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have created a common component for header and inside that I am conditional rendering the view, but whenever the route changes I have to manually refresh the page to see the updated results.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      headerType: {
        home: ['/'],
        stepper: ['/decisionAid'],
      },
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { headerType } = this.state;
    let type = Object.keys(headerType).find(data =>
      headerType[data].includes(window.location.pathname),
    );
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <>
          <Header type={type} />
          <Switch>
            <>
              <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
              <Route path="/decisionAid" component={Stepper} />
              <Route path="/notFound" component={NotFound} />
            </>
          </Switch>
        </>
      </Router>
    );
  }
```

When I change the page then due to change in url the header should be automatically updated but I have to manually refresh it.

Comment: The component that `Header` lives inside is rendered only once, on page load.  Simply changing the route does not cause it to re-render.  If you want this behaviour, you need to keep a local state.

Comment: hello @Kyle thanks for your answer but I didn't fully got the part, do I need to import the Header separately in every of the component where it is needed, can please elaborate your answer more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for your header to have access to your URL, and have the `Header` re-render without re-rendering the whole `App` object, you can wrap your `Header` around the higher-order component `withRouter`: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md

Doing this lets you have access to `match`, `location`, and `history` in your props.

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

function Header(props) {
  const path = props.location.pathname.slice(1);

  return <h1>Hello {path}!</h1>;
}

const WrappedHeader = withRouter(Header);
```

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-boilerplate-8ucq4

Comment: Thank you so much @kyle,  It exactly worked as I was wanting